# Связь has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: связи, ruby-on-rails

Есть 2 модели (Catalog и Stage) связанные через has_and_belongs_to_many. Есть таблица

create_table "catalogs_stages", id: false, force: true do |t|

```
t.integer "catalog_id"
t.integer "stage_id"
```

end

И, наконец, есть форма в которой есть селект

...

```
<%= select_tag('stage[catalog_ids][]', options_from_collection_for_select(Catalog.all, :id, :title), {:class => "form-control multiselect", :multiple => "multiple"}) %>
```

...

Не совсем понятно как, получая хэш от формы (в виде "catalog_ids" => ['1','8']) записать данные значения в join таблицу для последующего использования, или банально при изменении Этапов чтобы увидеть какие Каталоги были выбраны для данного этапа

Answer (score 1):

При правильном указании отношений в моделях всё должно автоматом записаться при применении update_attributes.

Подробнее здесь:

http://v32.rusrails.ru/active-record-associations/hasandbelongstomany-association-reference

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

http://rails.hasbrains.ru/screencasts/21